# Difference between slf4j-log4j12 and log4j-slf4j-impl

Tags: log4j, log4j2

In some projects which used slf4j and log4j I can see dependencies like

```
compile('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:version')
compile('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:version')
compile('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:version')
```

But some projects use **slf4j-log4j12** instead of **log4j-slf4j-impl**. To my understanding they are both works like bridges between slf4j and log4j, but what's their difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those artifacts use different versions of Log4j:

- [`slf4j-log4j12`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12) is a bridge between SLF4J and Log4j 1.2. Its versioning follows SLF4J.
- [`slf4j-reload4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-reload4j) is a bridge between SLF4J and Reload4j (a clone of Log4j 1.2). Its versioning follows SLF4J.
- [`log4j-slf4j-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl) is a bridge between SLF4J 1.x (up to 1.7.x) and Log4j 2.x. Its versioning follows LOG4J2.
- [`log4j-slf4j2-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j2-impl) is a bridge between SLF4J 2.x (or higher) and Log4j 2.x. Its versioning follows LOG4J2.

Since Log4j 1.x reached end-of-life more than 7 years ago, there is no sense in using the first one in new software.

Comment: So, slf4j-log4j has no 2.x counterpart? If I upgrade to log4j2 I have to use log4j-slf4j-impl?

Comment: Yes, the SLF4J project released only a binding for Log4j 1.x (there will be no `slf4j-log4j2` artifact). The binding for Log4j 2.x is maintained by the Log4j project itself.

Comment: RBB, you have to use log4j-slf4j-impl assuming you are still on SLF4J 1, yes.

Comment: So which other dependencies (apart from `log4j-slf4j-impl`) should I add to my pom in order to use `log4j2` with `slf4j1x` ?

Comment: Technically `log4j-slf4j-impl` is just a bridge between SLF4J and Log4j API. You also should add a Log4j API implementation (e.g. `log4j-core`).