# GraphTraversalSource Causing log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter)

Tags: log4j, log4j2, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-java

## Problem

How-To-Fix [Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) Warnings
When Using [Tinkerpop-3](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/)-[Gremlin (Language)](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/gremlin.html)-[`GraphTraveralSource`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html)?

## Tried

`src/main/java/main.java`

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;

import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        logger.info("Hello world!");
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
    }
}
```

`src/java/main/resources/log4j2.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                     filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%p] [%c{1.}.%t] ::&#x09; %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%p] [%c{1.}.%t] ::&#x09; %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

`pom.xml` dependencies:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

## Expected

This works fine when I comment out `GraphTraversalSource` but fails when its commented back in. 
The Log4j2-logger does show the "Hello world!" fine just like System.out does. 
And this is just a copy-paste from an OrientDB setup that instead uses OrientGraph:

```java
        OrientGraph orientGraph = OrientGraph.open(configuration);
        GraphTraversalSource g = orientGraph.traversal();
```

## Actual

```bash
Hello world!
2023-04-28 09:14:06,725 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    Hello world!
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between slf4j-log4j12 and log4j-slf4j-impl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528201/difference-between-slf4j-log4j12-and-log4j-slf4j-impl)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I don't think so, I'm using Java-11 and Log4j2 just like their [changelog](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/changelog/) suggests.

Comment: you are using the SLF4J-to-Log4j 1.x bridge (`slf4j-log4j12`) instead of the SLF4J-to-Log4j 2.x bridge (`log4j-slf4j-impl`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Piotr P. Karwasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11748454/piotr-p-karwasz)!

Switching out the slf4j did fix my issue.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.7.5</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Note the `pom.xml` order did matter here;
Throws error if Janusgraph + Tinkerpop came before Log4j2 dependencies.

[image: Simple Project Tree]

```
│   pom.xml
│       
├───src
│   └───main
│       ├───java
│       │       Main.java
│       │
│       └───resources
│           │   log4j2.xml
│           │
│           └───conf
│                   remote-graph.properties
│                   remote-objects.yaml
```