# Log4j2 - Configuration file getting created but not writing

Tags: java, maven, logging, jboss, log4j2

Java maven war project - when the application starts  it should create file and write logs as per log4j2 configuration  - here the file is getting created and log4j2 is also taking - but the logs are not getting written to new file. pom, log4j2 and web-deployement files are given below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>VOMS</groupId>
    <artifactId>voms-bl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.90</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.services.sts</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-services-sts-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.services.wsn</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-services-wsn-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.services.wsn</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-services-wsn-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-boolean</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-bug671</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-dv</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.fastinfoset</groupId>
            <artifactId>FastInfoset</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>isorelax</groupId>
            <artifactId>isorelax</artifactId>
            <version>20030108</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rhino</groupId>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <version>1.7R2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.msv</groupId>
            <artifactId>msv-core</artifactId>
            <version>2011.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.oauth.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth-provider</artifactId>
            <version>20100527</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.oauth.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth</artifactId>
            <version>20100527</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.oval</groupId>
            <artifactId>oval</artifactId>
            <version>1.85</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>relaxngDatatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>relaxngDatatype</artifactId>
            <version>20020414</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sixdee.extra</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat_core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/tomcat_core.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ximpleware</groupId>
            <artifactId>vtd-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-commons-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4c</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd</groupId>
            <artifactId>xsdlib</artifactId>
            <version>2010.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--                 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>3.9.0.2155</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--                    <warName>VOMS_BL</warName>-->
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                            <!-- <includes>
                            <include>external.jar</include>
                        </includes>-->
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/deployment</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <!-- <includes>
                            <include>external.jar</include>
                        </includes>-->
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0.2155</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Jboss-deployment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
            <subsystem name="weld" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        
        <exclusions>
               <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
               <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
        </exclusions>
        
        <dependencies>
               <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true" />
               <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
        
   </deployment>
   
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">

   <!-- <properties>
        <property name="pattern">%highlight{[%-5d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} | %-5p | %-30c | %-3L ] :-> %m%n}{FATAL=Cyan, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=Normal, DEBUG=Normal, TRACE=Normal}</property>
    </properties> -->
 <properties>
         <property name="pattern">[VMS]::[VoMs]::[Instance1]::[%-5d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}]::[%t]::[]::[%X{transactionId}]::[%-5level]::[]::%F | %L | %m%n</property>
    </properties> 


 <Appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="A1" fileName="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/log/app.log" append="false" 
               filePattern="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/log/vomsBaseBL_%d{yyyyMMddHH}_%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile> 

    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="VoucherLog" fileName="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/log/vomsBaseVoucherLog.log" append="false" 
               filePattern="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/log/vomsBaseVoucherLog_%d{yyyyMMddHH}_%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    
    <RollingRandomAccessFile append="false"
        name="CdrFileLog" fileName="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/standalone/log/vomsBaseFileCDR.csv"
        filePattern="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/standalone/log/$${date:yyyy-MM}/vomsBaseFileCDR_%d{yyyyMMddHH}_%i.txt">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p (%F:%L)  - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    
    <RollingFile name="CdrFileLog" fileName="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/log/mm_bl_file_cdr.txt" append="true"
        filePattern="/opt/erecharge/VFP_VMS/VFP_Voms_BL/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/log/$${date:yyyy-MM}/mm_bl_file_cdr-%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <!--<CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="50 * * * * ?" />-->
             <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" /> 
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>  </Appenders>
  
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
   </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.sixdee.fw" level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.sixdee.voms.imp" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
    </Logger>
    
    <Logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
    </Logger>
    
    <Logger name="com.sixdee.voms.imp.cdr.EventCDRGenerator" level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="CdrFileLog"/>
    </Logger>
    
    <Logger name="com.sixdee.voms.imp.tool.VoucherPrinter" level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="VoucherLog"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="info"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
 
  </Configuration>
```

i change the log versions and tried with different dependencies also

Comment: This is a lot of configuration here that people would need to read and understand to be able to help.  Try to minimise the code you supply and also try to provide logs to help the readers understand more about the runtime behaviour.

Comment: ok  will reduce , i will update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a logging back-end creates a logging file, but no message appears in it, the most common reason is: messages are being logged to another back-end. My guess is that they end up in the NO-OP SLF4J back-end:

In your case you have the following logging dependencies (cf. `mvn dependency:list` or your IDE):

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- dependency:2.8:list (default-cli) @ log4j-sandbox ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
          ...
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
          ...
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.0:compile
          ...
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
          ...
```

They serve the following purposes:

- `commons-logging`, `log4j-api` and `slf4j-api` are proper logging APIs: your code or library code uses them directly,
- `log4j-over-slf4j` is a replacement for `log4j:log4j` (Log4j 1.x), which contained both an API and a back-end. This artifact only replaces the API and forwards all messages to SLF4J.
- `log4j-core` is a logging back-end: the Log4j API will use it to write messages.
- `slf4j-api` also has a no-op backend: if it is selected you'll get a
  message like in [this
  question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421612/11748454) on your
  console.
- the rest are various bridges between the APIs.

Looking at your dependencies:

- code written using the Log4j API will be logged correctly to Log4j Core,
- code written using SLF4J will be logged to the **NO-OP backend** (no other implementation of SLF4J is present on the classpath),
- code written using Commons Logging will be redirected to SLF4J (either through `jcl-over-slf4j` or `log4j-over-slf4j`).

To fix your logging stack you should:

- bump `commons-logging` to version 1.3.0 (which supports Log4j API and SLF4J directly, with a preference for the former),
- remove `jcl-over-slf4j`,
- try removing `log4j-over-slf4j`: some **old** libraries might still use Log4j 1.x **directly**, but it is unlikely. If you start getting runtime linkage errors regarding `org/apache/log4j/Logger`, you'll need to add the dependency again,
- add a bridge between SLF4J and Log4j API: in your case it is `log4j-slf4j-impl` (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70528201/11748454)).

**Remark:** The `jul-to-slf4j` artifact can be used to provide a redirection between `java.util.logging` and SLF4J. However, unlike other redirections, this can only be done **globally** for the entire application server or requires application server specific configuration. Therefore `jul-to-slf4j` is usually useless in a WAR file.

Comment: the issue is not solved jcl-over-slf4j this is not present and also change the common loggig version same result

Comment: Did you add `log4j-slf4j-impl`?